# Connect Office 365 Exchange Online through Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, office365

I am trying to perform some operations on Exchange online(Office 365) through powershell.

First I created a new powershell session and exported the modules to local as "o365", so that on any later operation I no need to use Import-PsSession to download the required modules

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$s = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName "Microsoft.Exchange" -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Export-PsSession -session $s -outputModule o365
```

---

Now, I am creating new session and importing the existing module "o365".

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$s = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName "Microsoft.Exchange" -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-Module o365
Get-DistributionGroup
```

While running the command "Get-DistributionGroup", powershell prompts me to enter the office 365 credentials once again. Is it possible to avoid entering the credentials once again? I don't want to use Import-PsSession, since it takes more time.

Answer (score 1):

It's prompting because you're asking it to each time. I would set up $cred by creating a new object.

```
#Initiate Get-Credential cmdlet and store inputs
$getcred = Get-Credential
$username = $getcred.UserName
$password = $getcred.Password 

$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
```

If you place the above in its own function, you wont have the issue of re-defining the $getcred variable. (That to most is obvious, but thought I'd cover that base)

Comment: I applied the above one, but still it asks for password. Now I am using Enter-PsSession, which suits by need and resolves the problem of no need of using Import-PsSession.

Comment: O365 does not accept basic credentials for authentication. AFAIK there is no way to automate the O365 login process in the user context. You need to create an Azure application and assign rights to read the required data within Azure. Then you need to login with the oauth-token from that application.