# Using System.Management.Automation and an exported session, how do I specify credentials for an O365 call?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm building a small console app that uses constructs in the `System.Management.Automation` namespace to connect to ExchangeOnline and perform various tasks. The overhead time of creating and importing a new session with each run during my dev & test is prohibitive.

Thus, I've elected to save the session to disk using `Export-PSSession`. This all works fine from a PowerShell prompt, like so:

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnline
Get-Mailbox
```

I'm prompted for my credentials, and off we go.

Unfortunately, the same can't be said for running the same sequence under `Automation`:

> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): "Exception calling "PromptForCredential" with "4" argument(s): "A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: Enter your credentials for https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/.""

How do I send my credentials to O365 when using `System.Management.Automation`?

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21719212) almost answers it, but not quite.

Here's my code.

**Implementation**

```
Friend Class Monad
  Implements IDisposable

  Public Sub New()
    Me.SessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault
    Me.Monad = PowerShell.Create
  End Sub

  Public Sub ImportModule(Modules As String())
    If Me.RunSpace.IsNotNothing Then
      Me.RunSpace.Dispose()
      Me.RunSpace = Nothing
    End If

    Me.SessionState.ImportPSModule(Modules)
    Me.RunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(Me.SessionState)
    Me.RunSpace.Open()
    Me.Invoker = New RunspaceInvoke(Me.RunSpace)
  End Sub

  Public Function ExecuteScript(Script As String) As Collection(Of PSObject)
    Dim oErrors As Collection(Of ErrorRecord)

    ExecuteScript = Me.Invoker.Invoke(Script)

    oErrors = Me.Monad.Streams.Error.ReadAll

    If oErrors.Count > 0 Then
      Throw New PowerShellException(oErrors)
    End If
  End Function

  Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(IsDisposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.IsDisposed Then
      If IsDisposing Then
        If Me.RunSpace.IsNotNothing Then Me.RunSpace.Dispose()
        If Me.Invoker.IsNotNothing Then Me.Invoker.Dispose()
        If Me.Monad.IsNotNothing Then Me.Monad.Dispose()

        Me.RunSpace = Nothing
        Me.Invoker = Nothing
        Me.Monad = Nothing
      End If
    End If

    Me.IsDisposed = True
  End Sub

  Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Me.Dispose(True)
  End Sub

  Private ReadOnly SessionState As InitialSessionState

  Private IsDisposed As Boolean
  Private RunSpace As Runspace
  Private Invoker As RunspaceInvoke
  Private Monad As PowerShell
End Class
```

**Call**

```
Friend Function GetMailbox() As IEnumerable(Of PSObject)
  Using oMonad As New Monad
    oMonad.ImportModule({"ExchangeOnline"})

    Return oMonad.ExecuteScript("Get-Mailbox")
  End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ExchangeOnline module has some issues with that.  It wants to be able to display an interactive modern authentication dialog, and there's no reliable way to stop it.  You can feed it credentials, but it will barf if it needs to display an interactive dialog (as it does for MFA).

For storing and retrieving the credentials, you can use ConvertFrom-SecureString and Export-Csv or Export-CliXml as in the answer from InteXX, but that will stop working if basic authentication is disabled for the account you're using, or after 13 October 2020 when basic auth is disabled in exchange online (see KB4521831 ref https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4521831/exchange-online-deprecating-basic-auth).  Until then, you can also use a module like VaultCredential to manage credentials (note that it won't work across accounts).

So the next question is probably how you get a token for modern auth and how you present it to Exchange Online to authenticate with powershell.  That's not hard at all.

You can bang against the endpoints with .NET web calls without too much effort, but it's easier to use one of the officially sanctioned libraries like ADAL.PS (deprecated) and MSAL.PS.  Go ahead and Install-Module -Name MSAL.PS from the powershell gallery.  Once it's there (and run Get-Module -Refresh -ListAvailable to make sure it can autoload) you can run:

```
$Token = Get-MsalToken -ClientId "a0c73c16-a7e3-4564-9a95-2bdf47383716" -RedirectUri "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" -Scopes "https://outlook.office365.com/AdminApi.AccessAsUser.All","https://outlook.office365.com/FfoPowerShell.AccessAsUser.All","https://outlook.office365.com/RemotePowerShell.AccessAsUser.All"
```

You can also add "-LoginHint " (i.e. probably your email address) to skip the initial locator prompt, and it might help to add "-TenantId '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'" (except use the actual GUID for your Azure AD tenant).

Once a token is acquired, MSAL will keep it in its cache and automatically refresh it for you.  This might make non-interactive use a little more difficult.  You can review preferred ways to deal with it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens), or work with the libraries or interfaces at a lower level (such as using AcquireTokenSilentAsync()).

To actually use the token against Exchange Online, you need to use basic auth.  It will still work even after they deprecate it, but it won't validate your account's password, it will only do other stuff like accept encoded tokens.  Basically you need to Get-PsSession -Credential $EncodedBasicCredential where $EncodedBasicCredential is constructed with your UPN as the username and the Base64-encoded authorization header value as the password.  For example:

```
$EncodedBasicCredential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new($Token.account.username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String ($Token.CreateAuthorizationHeader())))
```

Note that $Token.CreateAuthorizationHeader() just takes the value of $Token.AccessToken
and prepends it with "Bearer ".  Now all you need to do is create a New-PsSession with the appropriate ConnectionUri, ConfigurationName, and your credential object:

```
    $ExchangeOnlineSession = New-PSSession -Name ExchangeOnline -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveId?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true" -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Credential $EncodedBasicCredential -Authentication Basic
```

And you can import that to the parent session as you like:

```
$ExchangeOnlineModule = Import-PSSession -Session ($ExchangeOnlineSession) -WarningAction Ignore
```

To answer your specific question (how you specify credentials), it all depends on how you access your identity authority.  If you are using ADFS on premises and your script runs on premises, then you should be able to run the process as the desired identity and Get-MsalToken will automatically use integrated windows authentication against ADFS without prompting you.  If you are using PTA or native auth directly against Azure AD, then you'll need to look at creating a client application and using a secret or a certificate to authenticate against Azure AD to get your token.

I think this will be reasonably easy to translate from powershell to C#, but I'm a scripting sys admin, not a coder.

Comment: This is very good, thank you. I especially like the token aspect. But I'm unfamiliar with the colon-delimited syntax found in your `RedirectUri` parameter. Could you expound a little bit on that?

Comment: It's not really a syntax, and the delimiting is not really relevant to anything that either of us is likely to see.  It's basically a monolithic entity that tell MSAL that it's being invoked by a local program and can return the result directly, instead of encoding the result and sending it in an HTTP request to another destination.  It's also used for return validation.

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by editing the exported module.

- First, export your O365 credentials:

  `Get-Credential | Export-Clixml -Path D:\Modules\O365Credential.xml`
- With that XML file now in hand, open the module for editing in your preferred IDE
- Search for the function call `PromptForCredential`
- Note that the call is a part of a larger call to the `Set-PSImplicitRemotingSession` cmdlet
- Comment out that entire outer cmdlet call, e.g.:

  [image]
- Insert an uncommented copy of the call (optional: fix the broken indentation)
- For the `-Credential` parameter, replace the value with `$Credential`
- Above the new `Set-PSImplicitRemotingSession` call, add this line:

  `$Credential = Import-Clixml -Path D:\Modules\O365Credential.xml`
- Your finished code should look something like this:

  [image]
- Save the module

To test, open a new PowerShell prompt and import the updated module. Run `Get-Mailbox`. You should receive a list of the mailboxes hosted by your O365 tenant, without being prompted for credentials.

Note that the module uses and decrements a `RunSpace` connection against your quota. You'll want to close that connection gracefully when you're done with your session:

```
Get-PSSession | Where-Object { $_.ConfigurationName -eq 'Microsoft.Exchange' } | Remove-PSSession -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Now you can import and use the module under the `System.Management.Automation` namespace, as shown in the VB.NET code above.